# Fabric requesting dSYM that's not in archive or iTunes Connect dSYM file

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I have an app with Crashlytics installed. To get the dSYM files for it, I've always gone to Window/Organizer, right click to show in finder, right click "show package contents" and go to the dSYM directory to get them.

In this instance, Crashlytics is saying it's missing a dSYM file which is a random string of numbers and letters (`65cbd90a2b443d36ab7a6a419b797a71`). When I go to look for it using the methodology described above, I'm only seeing a file named `MyApp.app.dSYM` and dSYM files for several frameworks I've incorporated via CocoaPods. I tried using dragging and dropping that file, but Fabric insists on the random string.

I've tried showing package contents of `MyApp.app.dSYM`, but don't see anything inside it except a "Contents" folder and a "Resources" folder w/ a DWARF subdirectory and a file with no extension called "My App".

Upon reviewing this post, I am 99% certain I can't just [build an archive and resubmit it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22460268/4475605).

I've also tried downloading the dSYM directly from iTunesConnect, as outlined [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35374388/4475605).

I tried uploading that dSYM "as is" as well as zipping it (dSYM.zip), but Fabric still wants that random string that doesn't seem to exist in either the local archive nor the dSYM on iTunesConnect.

Any suggestions re: additional methods I might get the dSYM file Crashlytics is asking for are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're almost there when you download the DSYM package from iTunes Connect! After downloading, add a .zip extension, and double click to unzip it.

In the folder of DSYMs produced, there will be one titled `65cbd90a2b443d36ab7a6a419b797a71` (the one Crashlytics is asking for). If it's not there - double check you are looking at the same builds on Crashlytics and iTunes connect.

**Upload just that file to Crashlytics.**

Problem solved.

Comment: Jeez! That was EASY! The file I'd downloaded from iTunes Connect was titled `dSYMS`. I was compressing that and attempting to upload it. I didn't realize it was already a `zip` file with no extension on it.

Comment: Build and version match but the Crashlytics is simply asking for a dsym that's not in the iTunes archive.. Done this many times and there's no chance that the crashes are coming from somewhere else..

Answer (score 7):

For non-Bitcode enabled apps, `Crashlytics` will automatically upload your `dSYMs`. If you have enabled `Bitcode` in your app then you need to upload dSYMs Manually.

Bitcode enabled applications are required to download their dSYM from `Xcode` and then upload it to Crashlytics in order to symbolicate the crashes. DSYMs for Bitcode enabled apps can be downloaded from Xcode’s Organizer. Select the specific Archive of your app and then hit the “Download dSYMs” button which will insert the Bitcode compiled dSYMs into the original Archive.

[image]

### Uploading dSYMs Manually

If you find that dSYMs aren’t being picked up, you can add them manually by going to your [app settings page](https://fabric.io/settings/apps), selecting an app, and click on the “Missing DSYMs” tab to upload the dSYM.

[image]

To help find where the dSYM is located, run this command in an open terminal:

```
mdfind "com_apple_xcode_dsym_uuids == <UUID>"
```

To find all dSYM try

```
mdfind "com_apple_xcode_dsym_uuids == *"
```

Also, if you upload a dSYM to `Fabric`, you should check that the UUID matches the one that is missing. Running this command in an open terminal will give you the UUID of the dSYM.

```
dwarfdump -u <PathToYourAppsDsym>
```

### Reference

[Crashlytics Advanced Setup](https://docs.fabric.io/ios/crashlytics/advanced-setup.html)

Answer (score 2):

When you create a binary, the symbols are located at specific locations inside the file. When there are no symbols, the crash log will indicate offsets from certain points in the binary e.g. `someFramework.someFunction +100`

So a dSYM file is created to help index inside that specific binary. Re-archiving a modified code base or project will result in different offsets inside the new binary, so you cannot simply re-archive and upload.

This is why tagging your git repo with e.g release-v2.1 is important, so if you needed to you could go back and re-archive and the offsets should be the same.

As far as Fabric works, it requires a zipped version of the dSYM file, that number you posted is probably a hash of the zip file, I'm not 100% certain.

If you have the Fabric app installed on your system, running a version on the device should cause an automatic upload of the dSYM file (which can destroy upload bandwidth if you repeatedly build and run a project, where it will still upload each dSYM file per build).

You're best option would be to find the exact point in time in your git repo, and rerun the app in the simulator, this should upload the dSYM and hopefully pair to the old one, although I'm not sure it will work. Otherwise, if you think you have the exact dSYM, try zipping it and uploading it.

If that doesn't work, you will have to go the old-school way and re-symbolicate it manually using the terminal and the offsets in the crash log. It takes a bit of time, but its doable using [atos](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/atos.1.html)

```
atos [-o AppName.app/AppName] [-l loadAddress] [-arch architecture]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I learned a little, but I'm still where I started with this. I think I'm going to just do a .01 release and ensure Fabric has the dSYM info before I turn it loose in the wild.

Comment: Using this method will the regenerated dSym get the same UUID as before?

Comment: No, dSYM will work only with the binary that was made along with it.