# XCode 7.3 "no dSYMs available for download"

Tags: ios, xcode7, app-store-connect, dsym

If I click the "Download dSYMs button for the Archive that I have uploaded to the App Store in XCodes Organizer window I get a message to say that "There are no dSYMs available for download".

In iTunes Connect if I select my app, then go to Activy | All Builds | Build Details I do not find a link to download the dSYMs - according to a number of posts I have found there should be a link available from there.

Why are these dSYMS not available for my app - I have been able to access them in the past.

Comment: I am facing the same problem right now. If you need the dSYM you can get it from the archive. Select it in the organizer -> show in Finder -> copy it ->  change to *.zip -> unzip.

Comment: @LoVo - I had tried this - however the dSYMS folder in the archive is empty.

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22460058/how-is-a-dsym-file-created

Comment: @AlexKosyakov Unfortunately that did not help - I already have the correct settings relating to stripping of symbols for my release build

Comment: @daveywc 
Did you check the 'Build Settings'? For your target under 'Build Options' the 'Debug Information Format' has to be 'DWARF with dSYM File' for your desired configuration that a dSYM file can be created.

Answer (score 0):

Check *Build Settings > Build Options > Debug Information Format*, if your selection is DWARF, there will not generate .dSYM file. You should choose the DWARF with dSYM File, then you can download the .dSYM file.

[image: dSYM]

Comment: This does not work. same error message "No dSYMs were found for Version 1.0.2 Build 5."