# How to read crash report in HockeyApp

Tags: ios, objective-c, hockeyapp

I'm testing the framework HockeyApps for testing apps with iOS, it seems I added successfully my app.

I added a code which is triggered after the user touches a button, the code is very simple:

```
- (IBAction)didClickAuthenticateOptions:(id)sender {

    NSString *s = @"x";
    id obj = s;
    NSArray *arr = obj;

    NSLog(@"the array has the following lenght:");
    NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)[arr count]);
}
```

this code will terminate with a crash on my app.

I installed and executed my app normally on my iPhone, and the crash report was sent to my site:

[image: crash report page]

but when I opened the crash report, I expected to get information about the file, method, line of code that provoked the crash

[image]

when I clicked on "view raw log" I got all this:

[raw log](http://textuploader.com/5iexo)

How to find the method, line and code that provoked the crash in all that log???

thanks in advance for the support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you did not yet upload the correct [dSYM files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22460058/how-is-a-dsym-file-created) to HockeyApp. They are needed to translate the cryptic memory addresses back to readable filenames, method names, and line numbers.

There some more info on how to find the correct dSYM [here](https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-ios-mac-os-x-tvos/how-to-solve-symbolication-problems).

Comment: I tried to find it in xcode and iTunes connect but I couldn't find that file, l added more details on my question Lukas Spieß

Comment: you were right, instead of downloading and installing the app from the page, I just Ran the program from xcode, that may generate another dSYM file, when I installed the correct file, it worked perfectly, thanks

Comment: Glad to hear I could help :)

Comment: @JesúsAyala Would you mind cleaning up your question a bit? Right now it's very long and contains a lot of confusing information.

Comment: Do you know, if I upload the correct dSYM after the crashes has occurred, will I be able to read past crashes, from before I uploaded it? If so, how long will it take? I uploaded the correct dSYM now, but the recent crashes are still not translated..

Comment: What lucas mentioned is the right answer and I figure it out by following this link from Hockey app: https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-ios-mac-os-x-tvos/how-to-manually-upload-and-symbolicate-a-crash